# Dataset too big for RAM, how to do efficient epochs

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn, bigdata

I currently am working with a dataset of about 2 million objects. Before I train on them I have to load them from disk and perform some preprocessing (that makes the dataset much bigger, so that it would be inefficient to save the post-processed data).

Right now I just load and train in small batches, but if I want to train for multiple epochs on the full dataset, I would have to load all the data from the previous epoch multiple times, which ends up taking a lot of time. The alternative is training for multiple epochs on the smaller batches of data before moving onto the next batch. Could the second method result in any issues (like overfitting)? And is there any other, better way to do this? I'm using tflearn with Python 3 if there are any built-in methods using that.

tl;dr: Is it okay to train for multiple epochs on subsets of data before training for a single epoch on all the data

Comment: If you are using mini-batches, usually the epoch doesn't end until you iterate over all the examples using small batches. But you want to train on the same batch multiple epochs and then move on to next batch and train it multiple times? Did I get it correct?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that

Comment: I can't see any gain on that strategy, your gradient may end up in a bad place after an epoch due to the selection of the current batch. It would be noisy and may not even converge. You would need to shuffle and train the whole set over and over for it to give you a decent result, which would take a lot of time. You can just use mini-batch algorithm and get the same memory benefits, which is also arguably better than training on full batch.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was worried about. Thank you!

Comment: How are you accessing the files on disk? Perhaps you should look into numpy memmap. You can use a range array to shuffle and access indices of your dataset using the byte-offset argument to numpys memmap